# Azure Continues Job fails randomly with Job failed due to exit code -532462766

Tags: multithreading, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I have developed Azure Job which is set to continues with Azure Queue triggered(batch size 32).

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("%queuename%")] string message,
        DateTimeOffset expirationTime,
        DateTimeOffset insertionTime,
        DateTimeOffset nextVisibleTime,
        string id,
        string popReceipt,
        int dequeueCount,
        string queueTrigger,
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount,
        ILogger log)
{
        //Code goes here
}
```

Memory usage shows below error

[image]

Full report shows this

[image]

It works well but randomly the job fails with below error

> [07/21/2019 07:05:12 > efe1a8: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
>   **[07/21/2019 14:01:37 > efe1a8: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766** [07/21/2019 14:01:37 > efe1a8: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 0 seconds [07/21/2019 14:01:37 > efe1a8: SYS INFO]
>   Status changed to PendingRestart [07/21/2019 14:01:37 > efe1a8: SYS
>   INFO] Run script 'MyWebJob.exe' with script host -
>   'WindowsScriptHost' [07/21/2019 14:01:37 > efe1a8: SYS INFO] Status
>   changed to Running

Event viewer shows below error

```
<Event>
        <System>
            <Provider Name=".NET Runtime"/>
            <EventID>1026</EventID>
            <Level>1</Level>
            <Task>0</Task>
            <Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
            <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-07-21T14:01:35Z"/>
            <EventRecordID>686664656</EventRecordID>
            <Channel>Application</Channel>
            <Computer>RD2818783928E7</Computer>
            <Security/>
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data>Application: TCT.Provisioning.WebJob.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.APMWithTimeout.Begin(System.Func`3&lt;System.AsyncCallback,System.Object,System.IAsyncResult&gt;, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object, System.TimeSpan)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.APMWithTimeout.RunWithTimeout(System.Func`3&lt;System.AsyncCallback,System.Object,System.IAsyncResult&gt;, System.AsyncCallback, System.Threading.TimerCallback, System.Object, System.TimeSpan)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.BeginGetResponse[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.ExecutionState`1&lt;System.__Canon&gt;)

Exception Info: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.EndUpdateMessage(System.IAsyncResult)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions+&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;CreateCallbackVoid&gt;b__3(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.UpdateQueueMessageVisibilityCommand+&lt;ExecuteAsync&gt;d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.TaskSeriesTimer+&lt;RunAsync&gt;d__14.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.WebJobsExceptionHandler+&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3_0.&lt;OnUnhandledExceptionAsync&gt;b__0()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

</Data>
        </EventData>
    </Event>
```

**Updated 7/26/2019**

After doing more research I added below code to my main method to catch the unhanded exception

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
        static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error occurred in Program.Application_ThreadException(): {0}", args.Exception);
        }
        static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error occurred in Program.CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(): {0}", (args.ExceptionObject as Exception));
        }
```

Based on recommendation from below

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/755

updated my main with below code as well

```
// Set this immediately so that it's used by all requests.
// Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#jobhost-servicepointmanager-settings
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = Int32.MaxValue;
System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);
```

After doing all of above changes got below error

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: There were not enough
>   free threads in the ThreadPool to complete the operation.  --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There were not enough free threads
>   in the ThreadPool to complete the operation.  at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state)  at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.APMWithTimeout.Begin(Func`3
>   beginMethod, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, TimeSpan timeout)
>   in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\APMWithTimeout.cs:line 60  at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.APMWithTimeout.RunWithTimeout(Func`3
>   beginMethod, AsyncCallback callback, TimerCallback timeoutCallback,
>   Object state, TimeSpan timeout) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\APMWithTimeout.cs:line 35  at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.BeginGetResponse[T](ExecutionState`1
>   executionState) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line
>   243
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult
>   result) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line
>   50  at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.EndUpdateMessage(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Queue\CloudQueue.cs:line
>   1474  at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.cs:line
>   114
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown  ---  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)  at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.UpdateQueueMessageVisibilityCommand.d__5.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown  ---  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)  at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.TaskSeriesTimer.d__14.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown  ---  at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.WebJobsExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)  at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)  at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)  at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)  at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() Request Information
>   RequestID: RequestDate: StatusMessage:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There were not enough free threads
>   in the ThreadPool to complete the operation.  at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state)  at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.APMWithTimeout.Begin(Func`3
>   beginMethod, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, TimeSpan timeout)
>   in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\APMWithTimeout.cs:line 60  at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.APMWithTimeout.RunWithTimeout(Func`3
>   beginMethod, AsyncCallback callback, TimerCallback timeoutCallback,
>   Object state, TimeSpan timeout) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\APMWithTimeout.cs:line 35  at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.BeginGetResponse[T](ExecutionState`1
>   executionState) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line
>   243

Comment: looks like `unhandled exception` from your code. Surround your code with `try catch` block and catch the actual exception with its stacktrace and throw it on the log.logInfo(ex.Message) and it will let you find what exact error

Comment: @HariHaran Thanks for the response. I do have try catch block but in my case application is crashing. Also its so random that I am unable to identify the root cause. I am also wondering why event log shows  Framework Version: v4.0.30319 where I am on v4.7 in azure and v4.7.2 in my console application.

Comment: so is it not entering catch block for exceptions ?

Comment: @HariHaran Nop. It just crashes.

Comment: cant help you if you dont post relevant code

Comment: @HariHaran Added more details. Also got another thread who is having similar issues.https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/755

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Added more details. Also got another thread who is having similar issues.github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/755